# Camel case program in erlang

Tags: string, erlang, camelcasing

I have a string "value" and need to convert it to "Value" how can we do that using camel case
Output :
value = Value

Comment: Use Elixir? https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Macro.html#camelize/1 :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`string:titlecase/1`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/string.html#titlecase-1):

```erlang
> string:titlecase("value").
"Value"
```

Edit: this would technically not be a full camel case implementation (which would need to split on some character and title case each chunk), but it satisfies your example.

For converting `snake_case` to `CamelCase`, for instance, you could do:

```erlang
> String = "hello_world",
  Chunks = string:split(String, "_"),
  Chunks2 = lists:map(fun string:titlecase/1, Chunks),
  string:join(Chunks2, "").
"HelloWorld"
```